# How do I apply bootstrap's clearfix to my code?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, clearfix

I'm using a wysiwyg editor in my project, and part of this editor includes the option to set images' position to left, right, inline. When I choose left, it gives it the float-left feature. I'm wondering how I can make it so the div containing my content automatically expands to allow for the floating images.

Below is my code for the posts partial I use in my project

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="text">
    <%= link_to post.title, post_path(post), class: "h1" %>
    <p class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted on <%= post.created_at.to_formatted_s :long %></p>
    <hr>
    <p><%= post.content.html_safe %></p><hr>
    <p>
      <% post.tags.any? %>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group" aria-label="...">
          <% post.tags.each do |tag| %>
              <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag), class: "btn btn-info" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more which issue you are facing. From above statement all is unclear and confusing.

Comment: I've heard of a built in 'clearfix' class in Bootstrap which I believe is meant to help with floating issues similar to this one, but I can't find any documentation or anything online with instructions of how to actually apply this. 

I basically have an image within my
    <p><% post.content %></p>
section, which currently has a float class to it, causing it to overlap from my thumbnail div

Comment: Add class `clearfix` on parent of floating element. Like `<div class="text clearfix">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use clearfix outside of bootstrap. As long as you define it in your CSS like this:

```
.clearfix::after {
content: " ";
display: table;
clear: both; }
```

And apply the "clearfix" class to any element it requires, like this:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

It should work.

Comment: Managed to sort this, just needed to add the clearfix class to the <p> tag containing my content, this was due to this tag needing to push down the button group below it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13056247)

Comment: @JonathanArgentiero How does this not provide an answer to the question? This is clearly an answer. Now, it's not a *good* answer...